# Does flashbots protect send your transaction to a flashbots MEV auction?

Tags: flashbots

According to the [flashbots docs](https://docs.flashbots.net/flashbots-protect/overview), it says:

> Flashbots Protect makes it easy for everyday users and developers to use Flashbots for frontrunning protection.

However, it goes on to say:

> We abstract away the complexity of submitting bundles to the Flashbots Auction and make integrating as simple as adding a URL to MetaMask.

This makes me think it'll protect me from *public* sandwich and front-running bots, but not *flashbots* sandwich and front-running bots.

It *then* goes on to say that all transactions are sent the the [MEV-Share](https://docs.flashbots.net/flashbots-protect/rpc/mev-share) node.

> Flashbots Protect users' transactions automatically flow to the Flashbots MEV-Share Node, which returns them up to 90% of the MEV that their transactions create.

Which makes me think, "ok, clearly Flashbot protect is *not* protecting me from MEV... what gives?"

Do I have that correct?

Answer (score 1):

You can't sandwich mev-share transactions, only backrun them.

If just sending a private transaction, only the hash shows up for searchers.
If using mev-share privacy options you can choose what to share in order to make it easier for a searcher to create a bundle that includes it and then receive some of the profits. But again it is backrun only.

> Currently, MEV-Share only allows constructing bundles containing a single input and a single backrun. If the input is also a bundle, the rule applies recursively to that nested bundle. Concretely this means that searchers can only place hashes in the first position of their bundles; and each bundle may include up to one hash. The MEV-Share Node will reject any bundles that violate these rules. This ensures that searchers cannot frontrun users in-protocol.

Comment: So... flashbots protect protects me from most of the MEV, and the stuff it doesn't it gives me back with MEV-share? There is no guarantee that flashbots isn't secretly showing the transaction to a small group of searchers tho right?

Comment: Think that is a fair way to put it, though would not consider it failure to protect against mev, as the back run only takes advantage of mev your txn would have organically created.
Cannot do much with a hash outside of blind fire back runs, so assuming the details aren't being shared outside the protocol it's effective protection.

Comment: Mevshare is very new, (have logged hundreds of thousands of txn's from stream) and it is a minute number that share more than hash, so there is some lack of order flow and seems like less searchers focused on building kickback bundles.
Too soon to pass judgment on effectiveness, great concept I would hope to encourage more orders through.

There are some additional points of trust with introduction of "matchmaker", and I think yes it's always been possible that your transaction details are shared with some select group, though don't have any evidence of this.